# Intellij Idea location of generated constructor

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been using the Intellij Idea constructor generator as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-constructors.html and it's been working fine except for the location of generated constructors.

"The generated constructors are inserted at the points defined in the Order of Members section of the Code Style settings. By default, the code generator places constructors after the fields."

The Code Style settings doesn't have anything about Order of Members that I can find, and the code generator seems to be just putting constructors wherever the cursor happens to be at the time.

How do you get the code generator to put them in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cursor is located in a position where IntelliJ can validly insert a constructor then IntelliJ will insert the generated constructor in that position.

If the cursor is not located in a position where IntelliJ can validly insert a constructor then IntelliJ will insert the generated constructor according to the "Order of Members".

To verify this ...

1. Place your cursor on the class name and then invoke the constructor generator (`Code > Generate ... > Constructor`) and the generated constructor will be inserted according to "Order of Members"; typically after member declarations and any other constructors already present in the class.
2. Place your cursor on an empty line within the class and then invoke the constructor generator (`Code > Generate ... > Constructor`) and the generated constructor will be inserted at your cursor location.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java? There, you'll find an "Arrangement" tab that lets you define the order of fields, methods and constructors:

[image: img]